# What is full page caching

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

I am working on Magento(EE). I found a term "Full page caching". Can any one please tell me what is "full page caching in Magento or in Zend ?

Comment: and, hmm, did you like tried to lookup the term on google?

Comment: I always find it funny when I see these comments asking the OP if he used Google, when I myself used Google and got the question as my first hit. My point is that it was useful that the person asked the question, even from the perspective of someone that uses Google.

Answer (score 7):

Caching the full page?

As in every thing that is generated from a script is written to HTML and served next time, improving performance (by reducing load and not having to generate the page for every visit).

However this comes as the disadvantage of having occasionally out of date pages.

If you website isn't getting a significant amount of hits, enabling full page caching or caching of all the HTML it going to make little difference

Comment: Hello Pez, Thank you so much for your answer. I just want to know about the technical difference between normal caching and full page caching ?

Comment: I'd imagine that it simply means the entire page is cached as one, whereas normally only some parts of the page are cached or they are stored as separate files.

Answer (score 4):

Magento is a shopping website CMS.

It simple means that to boost the performance of the website, it will cache (store in buffer) the HTML output of a particular page. For example, your homepage, everytime user opens your homepage, the PHP behind it, has to fetch the information from database, parse it with related views and then display the final HTML output, LOTSA processing.

Instead, caching will store the HTML output in its buffer and when user comes in, it will show the HTML cached output rather going to the database *and stuff*. However, life of cache has to be defined although modern cache plugins will check for any changes in the output data and update the cache as is.

Simple?